# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1. "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" failed

Tags: java, flutter, android-emulator, build.gradle

I tried running my flutter app without debugging in android emulator on vs code but it failed and I got the following message in the debug console:- (Here's the link to the codebase https://github.com/Rachita-Dongre/productivityplus)
'''
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 64 in debug mode...

main.dart:1
Checking the license for package Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses

License for package Android SDK Tools accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".

"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" ready.

Installing Android SDK Tools in C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools

"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" complete.

"Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" finished.

Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)".

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" ready.

Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 in C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\30.0.3

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" complete.

"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3 (revision: 30.0.3)" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 33 in C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\licenses

License for package Android SDK Platform 33 accepted.

Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)".

Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 33: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.temp\PackageOperation01\unzip\android-13\data\res\drawable-ldpi\sym_keyboard_num5.png.:

java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Android\sdk.temp\PackageOperation01\unzip\android-13\data\res\drawable-ldpi\sym_keyboard_num5.png
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:87)

```
at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)

at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)

at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:235)

at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:371)

at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:648)
```

at com.android.repository.util.InstallerUtil.unzip(InstallerUtil.java:138)

```
at com.android.repository.impl.installer.BasicInstaller.doPrepare(BasicInstaller.java:90)

at com.android.repository.impl.installer.AbstractPackageOperation.prepare(AbstractPackageOperation.java:335)

at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installRemotePackages(DefaultSdkLoader.java:365)

at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.installTarget(DefaultSdkLoader.java:244)

at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:161)
```

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:128)

```
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkFullLoadingStrategy.init(SdkFullLoadingStrategy.kt:49)

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkFullLoadingStrategy.getTargetBootClasspath(SdkFullLoadingStrategy.kt:71)

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkLoadingStrategy.getTargetBootClasspath(SdkLoadingStrategy.kt:36)

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService$VersionedSdkLoader$targetBootClasspathProvider$1.call(SdkComponents.kt:184)

at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkComponentsBuildService$VersionedSdkLoader$targetBootClasspathProvider$1.call(SdkComponents.kt:183)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProvider.calculateOwnValue(DefaultProvider.java:72)
```

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:102)

```
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.calculateOwnValue(FlatMapProvider.java:50)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractMinimalProvider.calculateValue(AbstractMinimalProvider.java:102)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.backingProvider(FlatMapProvider.java:62)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.FlatMapProvider.getProducer(FlatMapProvider.java:71)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.getProducer(Collectors.java:235)
```

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.getProducer(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:389)

```
at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.Collectors$ElementsFromCollectionProvider.getProducer(Collectors.java:235)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$PlusCollector.getProducer(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:465)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractCollectionProperty$CollectingSupplier.getProducer(AbstractCollectionProperty.java:389)

at org.gradle.api.internal.provider.AbstractProperty.getProducer(AbstractProperty.java:178)
```

at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.ProviderBackedFileCollection.visitDependencies(ProviderBackedFileCollection.java:50)

```
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:103)

at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmptyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:213)

at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:121)

at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:73)

at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:66)

at org.gradle.execution.plan.TaskDependencyResolver.resolveDependenciesFor(TaskDependencyResolver.java:49)
```

at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.getDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:162)

```
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNode.resolveDependencies(LocalTaskNode.java:136)

at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.doAddNodes(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:208)

at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:173)

at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultExecutionPlan.addEntryTasks(DefaultExecutionPlan.java:158)

at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
```

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:49)

```
at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:62)

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:48)

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:49)

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.lambda$select$0(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
```

at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)

```
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)

at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:197)

at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$DefaultBuildProjectRegistry.withMutableStateOfAllProjects(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:190)

at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:35)
```

at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.prepareForTaskExecution(DefaultTaskExecutionPreparer.java:42)

```
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$1(VintageBuildModelController.java:81)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:110)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:125)

at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:121)
```

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:109)

```
at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.scheduleRequestedTasks(VintageBuildModelController.java:81)

at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController$DefaultWorkGraphBuilder.addRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:242)

at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$4(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)

at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkPreparer.java:41)

at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.populateTaskGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:138)
```

at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer$PopulateWorkGraph.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:89)

```
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
```

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)

```
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)

at org.gradle.internal.build.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.populateWorkGraph(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkPreparer.java:66)

at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$populateWorkGraph$5(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$1(StateTransitionController.java:110)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$inState$2(StateTransitionController.java:125)

at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:121)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.inState(StateTransitionController.java:109)
```

at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:143)

```
at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildWorkGraphController$DefaultBuildWorkGraph.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildWorkGraphController.java:126)

at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultBuildController.populateWorkGraph(DefaultBuildController.java:71)

at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraphBuilder.withWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:142)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.lambda$scheduleRequestedTasks$0(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:34)

at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph$1.run(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:170)
```

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)

```
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
```

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)

```
at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph$DefaultBuildTreeWorkGraph.scheduleWork(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:167)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.scheduleRequestedTasks(DefaultBuildTreeWorkPreparer.java:34)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$doScheduleAndRunTasks$2(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:89)

at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.withNewWorkGraph(DefaultIncludedBuildTaskGraph.java:101)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.doScheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:88)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
```

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)

```
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)

at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.scheduleAndRunTasks(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:69)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:31)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)

```
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)

at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)

```
at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)

at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)

```
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
```

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)

```
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)

at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)

at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)

at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)

```
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)

at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
```

at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)

```
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
```

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)

```
at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)

at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)

```
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)

```
at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)

```
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
```

at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)

```
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)

at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)

at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)

at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
```

at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

"Install Android SDK Platform 33 (revision: 2)" failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to install the following SDK components:
> platforms;android-33 Android SDK Platform 33
> Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 56s

Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Exited (sigterm)
'''

I wasn't able to run the app on emulator because of not having java installed so I installed it and the tried to run the app again on android emulator but the task failed and I got the above message in debug console.